# What is the difference between free-fall timescale and dynamical timescale?

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy, stars

I have encountered these terms quite often in astronomical textbooks, and sometimes they are used interchangeably. I have also heard that the free fall timescale is larger than dynamical timescale. Can someone please explain the difference between these two timescales?

Comment: I would think that would depend on context...

Comment: I thought they were literally the same. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free-fall_time

Comment: This link describes dynamical time: https://www.astro.princeton.edu/~gk/A403/timescales.pdf